# Extend the passcode lock timeout on iPhone 4S and iOS 5 connected to exchange

Tags: ios, jailbreak, password, find-my-iphone

## Preface

I have an iPhone 4S running iOS 5 and to prevent Find Friends from asking for a password every time it is opened I have enabled the passcode lock and set it to the max of 4 hours. This is fine as in reality it means at most once a day BUT it is now connected to our works exchange server which apparently is aloud to force the iPhone to remove the 1 hours and 4 hours lock options meaning I have to put in the passcode lock almost every time now which I do not like.

## Attempts to fix

I have tried several tricks I found which apparently have been "fixed" by apple like disabling the exchange, changing the lock to 4 hours and re-enabling the exchange but this doesn't work any more.

I have found a few older posts about changing the "maxGracePeriod" in some of the iPhone config files like this post: http://modmyi.com/forums/member-written-iphone-news/700148-extending-time-passcode-lock.html#post5480817

So I jailbroke my iPhone and using iPhone Browser on my PC connecting to my now it and also iFile directly to look for these files but it appears that ether they have moved the files or my iPhone doesn't have this file.

## Question

SO:

- How can I remove the restriction Exchange puts on my iPhone of 15 mins max before the passcode is required?
- OR maybe remove the requirement for Find Friends to require the passcode lock at all *(I will amend the question to reflect this if this is the final result)*

Comment: just tried this on an iPhone 4S running iOS 5.1.1, and it always resets back to the 5 minutes max mark... I did get the options 1 hour and 4 hours, but after a few minutes, it reverts back to 5 minutes, and the options dissappear... It seems like the plist files are being re-written... too bad...

Comment: Mine iPhone 4S has been running iOS 5.1.1 since the JB came out and it is still at 4 hours. The longer times seemed to have been overwritten though but not the 4 hour one. I still have the same exchange server connected I always had. Not sure why yours is reverting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears I was slightly half wrong! The above mentioned post is correct and I managed to find the specified directory:

- /var/mobile/library/configurationProfiles/PublicInfo

but only with iFile (not iPhoneBrowser). So I edited the files mentioned: ***"change maxGracePeriod and maxInactivity to 14400 (it's in seconds, not in minutes) in the files EffectiveUserSettings.plist and Truth.plist."*** and after a re-spring "4 hours" appeared as an option! Also I can now see that directory in iPhoneBrowser (may have been a fault?)

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Oh and I now use 172800 (48 hours) now and never have to deal with this bar reboots ;)

Comment: For some reason this will reset randomly every now and then. It seems to happen to me every month or so with no significant change made or update done. (Maybe some app update like BiteSMS which I just updated and MAY have updated in the past before the reset.) Anyway reapplying solves it again. :)